# iOS9.1 --- can not pair ble device thourgh 'LightBlue'?

Tags: bluetooth, ios9.1

Today, I update iOS to iOS9.1. Really bad thing is that can not pair BLE device through 'LightBlue'.

iOS9.0.2 and earlier OS version are all OK.

Can anyone tell me what changed in Core Bluetooth?

I need to update my app to fix this bug in App store, what a bad thing about iOS9.1!

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you’ll want to do is reset your device’s Network Settings. To get that done go to Settings > General > Reset > Reset Network Settings. Your device will forget the Bluetooth device and you’ll now have to reconnect.

If that doesn’t dislodge your problem, you’ll want to try forgetting the Bluetooth connection. To do that go to Settings > Bluetooth > Select your connection using the circular blue i tab > Tap Forget this Device. Try reconnecting.

You can also try resetting all of your settings and there’s a chance it will work for you. To reset all of your settings go to Settings > General > Reset > Reset All Settings. This process could take a few minutes and after it’s done, your device’s settings will be restored to factory defaults. In other words, have your Wi-Fi passwords handy.

Comment: Thank for your suggestion, but what a bad one!